# How To Format Datetime like 2017-01-10T14:53:55.000+0000?

Tags: apex, soql, date, datetime, format

Using `Apex`, how can I format a `Datetime` variable the same way it is displayed in SOQL result? It seems that SOQL [uses the UTC format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

When I run the following query

```
SELECT CreatedDate FROM Account
```

I get the following datetime format:

```
2017-01-10T14:53:55.000+0000
```

[image: console query result]

Comment: Are you asking how to format a DateTime type into an ISO 8601 format or you have a DateTime in ISO 8601 format (as above returned from SOQL) and you are trying to format it in another manner? Related documentation: [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: @MarkPond I am looking to format a datetime to format like 2017-01-10T14:53:55.000+0000 using Apex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the example given in the [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) class and calling the `formatGMT(string)` method with a formatting string found in the Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) examples:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(1993, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3);
String formatted = myDateTime.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
system.debug(formatted);
```

Produces this result:

```
15:41:47:003 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|1993-06-06T10:03:03.000+0000
```